# How to check weather the user has performed a login using facebook sdk 4.0 in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to get Login status in my app.

This is what i want:

```
if(isUserLoggedIn()==true)
{
 //take him to main screen
}

else
{
  // take him to login screen
}
```

I am using Facebook SDK 4.0.1

**Edit**

```
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        tracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken old, AccessToken newToken) {

                if(newToken.isExpired())
                {
                    isLoggedIn=false;
                    Toast.makeText(FrontQuizify.this,"not logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    isLoggedIn=true;
                    Toast.makeText(FrontQuizify.this,"logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
        if(isLoggedIn==false) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

I am doing above on onCreate. This class doesn't have loggin button.

Comment: And uhm.. what have you tried?

Comment: I have done a lot, but i am stuck here when i want to check login status.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts Also I have tried AccessToken to check login status, do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the current profile in order to check weather the user has perform a login,

Try this.

```
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getCurrentProfile();
    if(profile != null)
    {
        //user  has logged in
    }
    else
    {
        //user  has not logged in
    }
```

Comment: It works :). But it only works on Activity that contain loginButton. Still i am not able to make it work where i want to be :|.

Comment: where you need to put that ?

Comment: In another activity which calls login Activity if loggin has not done yet.

Comment: you may keep the status in static variable where you can access among different activities.

Comment: But I have to initialize that class with login button before using it. But yes I can make it work using sharedPreferences :).

Comment: yep sharedPreferences more appropriate than runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps for facebook login for android. Login works based on tokens.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3#overview

Comment: So you are saying that i should use if(AccessToken!=null) -> then user is logged in. But it doesn't work at all i guess ?

Comment: Can you share your piece of code where you are trying to use this.